# How do I execute a standalone lua file in a separate instance of lua.exe?

Tags: windows, lua

I have a standalone lua file ("file.lua") I wish to run multiple instances of, each in its own lua.exe prompt.
I have another standalone lua file ("server.lua") which will be run first, and will be initiating the multiple instances of "file.lua" on demand.

I'm a newcomer to coding; so far I've tried os.execute and dofile. I assume that it's one of those,  with a set of arguments to instruct the Lua file to open in a unique window, but I can't seem to find any helpful information online with regards to running the .lua file separately.

I literally just need a line or function which would call the lua file up in a separate window/instance.

Assistance please?

Comment: `os.execute('lua file.lua')` should run `lua` interpreter (if `lua` is in path) in a new instance every time, but it is a blocking call and thus wouldn't return until the command terminates. Thus calling it multiple times in a loop means, to run each instance one after the other sequentially and not in parallel.

Comment: The issue with this method is that it does not open a new instance of the lua interpreter prompt with the 'file.lua' running in it.
It just runs 'file.lua' in the current prompt.
I need a solution which opens up a new lua.exe prompt window with 'file.lua' run immediately.

Comment: Just like what happens when I execute the 'file.lua' from windows; I can do this as many times as I want and they'll run in parallel, separate instances of lua.exe.

Comment: `os.execute("start lua file.lua")`